# Edit Links Missing in Top Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, edit, links

I created a list and the main site does not have the Edit Links option in the top navigation. The template showes as var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = 'BLANKINTERNET#0'and I am afraid to alter this to change the entire site as I am not managing this site however they have given me temporary Site Collection Administrator. I am not IT so don't want to alter something that would change the entire site.

I was hoping there would a setting that flips this option on without having to change templates.

Please advise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is available only for "Structural Navigation" option under "Navigation Settings" on publishing sites.

Go to site settings -> Navigation under Look and Feel -> Check whether Structural Navigation.